# import and access re-usable static methods (AndroidStudio)

Tags: android, code-reuse

In my former programmer-career I had developed hundreds of small utility functions re-usable in multiple programs .
Now in Android ( strange & new to me ) I would like to do something alike , utilities as playing a sound at certain events , make some standard dialogs etc..
I tried with a new package es.utils with an "add no activity"  .
Therein I added a java-class with a private constructor ( so the class cannot be instantiated ) , all the methods in that class declared static.
These  methods will be my "functions" ( compare with Javas Math-class ) .
So far so good but how do I call or import these methods in my common-apps & make them visible for AndroidStudio? 
Paste and Copy source-code is not a serious option .
All the text-books and tutorials I have consulted remain silent about this theme . 
Someone with a practical suggestion ? Thanks in advance!
Eric.S

Answer (score 0):

Today Android Studio uses gradle as the build mechanism.

You can, do some pretty configuring with references as library modules for your own usage.

But if you pretend to make it public you can:

- Generate AAR;
- Generate JAR if it doesnt contains the resources folders and AndroidManifest
- publish as a gradle artefact trough jcenter() and maven() repos [recommended]

Answer (score 0):

I do this by creating an Android library project that contains all of my common reusable code.

I share the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/) then just use Gradle and [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/) to import the library into whatever project I want to use.

Github lets me create version releases so I can safely keep a "point in time" version of my library in case any updates to the library cause changes that could break the projects that use it.

Comment: @Marcos : Thanks  for the reply , both ways of doing this seems quite complicated . Considering that oldies as Cobol and C did this common problem much more elegantly , putting the compiled object code in a user-lib and letting the "linker' sort it all out , I wonder why such new and advanced product as Android does this so clumsy?

Comment: This is just the way I do it as it suits my needs. Doing the above means that in every project I want to use the library, I just add one line to the build.gradle and Android Studio then downloads and uses my library automatically. Hardly clumsy.  If you want a simple way, just import the library directly from disk into any project. You will then get a complete copy in your project.

Comment: I found another way to simulate a copy paste of the sources : symlinks or symbolic links (  a command-line afair known in Linux and modern versions of  MS-Windows ) Studio let us add files to our projects but not at this moment symlinks so we have to do it in terminal-mode .